# Move a container and all the children inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, contenteditable

I can not properly drag the 'father' box to another point on the page.
If I do not put `e.preventDefault` on, the browser ignores the directions on the range by moving the element without recreating another container.
I need to be able to move the container correctly .father, how can I do it?
The live code is [here](http://jsbin.com/kuravatala/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

```js
var span;
var clone;
var id;
window.onload = function() {
  id = document.getElementsByClassName('father')[0];
  var b = document.body;
  id.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart, false);
  id.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd, false);
  b.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
    dropp(event)
  }, false);
}

function dragStart() {
  span = document.getElementsByClassName('father')[0];
  clone = span.cloneNode(true);
}

function dragEnd() {
  if (document.getSelection) {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(clone);
  }
}

function dropp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<body contenteditable="true">
  <p> first paragraph </p>
  <p> second paragraph
    <span class="father">
   <img id="first-child" src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/Destinations/Africa/Mauritius/Mauritius---Beaches---Tropical-beach-large.jpg" width="200" height="auto">
   <span id="second-child" style="color:red;">Text</span>
    </span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This works fine...Check if it is helpful for you..

```js
  var makeMove;
  x0=0;
  y0=0;
  function move(e){
   if(makeMove){
    x1 = e.clientX;
    y1 = e.clientY;
    cx=x0+x1-x;
    cy=y0+y1-y;
    
    document.getElementById("main").style.left = cx +"px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.top = cy +"px";
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  }
  function mouseUp(e){
   makeMove=false;
   x0=cx;
   y0=cy;
  }
  function mouseDown(e){
   makeMove=true;
   x = e.clientX;
   y = e.clientY;
  }
```

```html
<body contenteditable="true">
    <p> first paragraph </p>
    <p  onmousemove="move(event)" onmouseup="mouseUp(event)" onmousedown="mouseDown(event)"> second paragraph
      <span class="father" id="main" style="position:relative;">
        <img id="first-child" src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/Destinations/Africa/Mauritius/Mauritius---Beaches---Tropical-beach-large.jpg" width="200" height="auto">
        <span id="second-child" style="color:red;">Text</span>
      </span>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution can not work in my case: I have to move the container by following the text, it must be part of the text.